# Lilypond: How to engrave lowercase chord symbols

Tags: lilypond

My goal is to engrave music for accordion and I would like to have my chords symbols as follows:

Bass tone: always uppercase: e.g. **A E D**

Chords: always lower case:
e.g. *major* chords **a e d**; *minor* chords **am em dm**

And together: **A am E e D d7**

In Lilypond you can force the lowercase only for the minors: `\set chordNameLowercaseMinor = ##t`

But I would like to have this possibility for the majors, sevens etc. as well...The bass tone is always uppercase, which is fine.

Comment: You can probably achieve something by overriding chordRootNamer and chordNoteNamer. Can you create a small snippet to show how you want to encode it with lilypond ?

Comment: Is this a standard chord format for accordian music? Lead sheets typically follow the guitar chord convention of using upper case for the primary note of the chord, followed by a combination of #, b (flat), m (minor), aug (augmented), maj (major), dim (diminished) etc, and then if an inversion is to be applied, a forward slash and the bass note. For example, D/F# would be first inversion of D, i.e. an F# bass tone with a D chord. This is easy to achieve in Lilypond as is the default behaviour for chords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This was asked and answered [elsewhere](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/How-to-engrave-lowercase-chord-symbols-tc195612.html), but in case it helps any future visitors, I'll add their results.)

### Fix #1

```
\version "2.19.58"

\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    chordNoteNamer = #note-name->markup
    chordRootNamer =
      #(lambda (pitch lowercase?) (note-name->markup pitch #t))
  }
}

\new ChordNames \chordmode { c:7 c:m7 c:7/+c c:m7/+c }
```

But this one has some problems with single bass pitch inputs, resulting in

### Fix #2

```
\version "2.19.58"

#(define-public (my-note-name->german-markup pitch lowercase?)
  (let* ((name (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
         (alt-semitones (inexact->exact (round (* (ly:pitch-alteration
pitch) 2))))
         (n-a (if (member (cons name alt-semitones) `((6 . -1) (6 . -2)))
                  (cons 7 (+ 1 alt-semitones))
                  (cons name alt-semitones)))
         (basic-list '("c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "a" "h" "b"))
         (list-to-use
           (if lowercase?
               basic-list
               (map string-upcase basic-list))))

    (make-line-markup
     (list
      (string-append
       (list-ref list-to-use (car n-a))
       (if (or (equal? (car n-a) 2) (equal? (car n-a) 5))
           (list-ref '( "ses" "s" "" "is" "isis") (+ 2 (cdr n-a)))
           (list-ref '("eses" "es" "" "is" "isis") (+ 2 (cdr n-a)))))))))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    chordNameFunction =
      #(lambda (in-pitches bass inversion context)
        (if (= (length in-pitches) 1)
            (my-note-name->german-markup (car in-pitches) #f)
            (ignatzek-chord-names
              in-pitches bass inversion context)))
    chordNoteNamer =
      #(lambda (pitch lowercase?)
      (my-note-name->german-markup pitch #f))
    chordRootNamer =
      #(lambda (pitch lowercase?)
      (my-note-name->german-markup pitch #t))
  }
}

\new ChordNames \chordmode { cis:7 cis:m7 c:7/+c c:m7/+c <ces> cis:1 }
```

This allows for single pitch inputs as `<c>` and `c:1`. Note that this latter example uses German notation, which one can adjust as necessary in the Scheme code.